# Calculate distribution of negative values per numerical column in df

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

What is a quick way to compute the % of negative values in a dataframe for each numerical column that has at least one negative value?

Currently I am able to calcuate it for each numerical value.

```
for i in range(1,len(df.columns)):
  if df.dtypes[df.columns[i]] in ['float64','int64','float32','int32']:
    negatives = np.sum(np.array(df.iloc[:,[i]] < 0))
    negativesP= "{:.2%}".format(negatives/len(df))
    print(df.columns[i], ": \n", negatives, "\t", negativesP)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `select_dtypes` to get only numerical columns with `np.number`, use `lt` to compare to 0 and `mean`. Then `format` with apply.

```
import numpy as np

# toy sample
np.random.seed(10)
n=100
d = {'a': np.random.randint(-10,10,n),
     'b': np.random.choice(list('abcdefgh'), size=n) ,
     'c':np.random.random(size=n)-0.5}
df = pd.DataFrame(d)

# this gives you only the percentage
print(df.select_dtypes(include=[np.number]).lt(0).mean().apply("{:.2%}".format))
#a    37.00%
#c    56.00%
#dtype: object
```

and if you want the count, you can also use `sum` like

```
_df = df.select_dtypes(include=[np.number]).lt(0)
print(
    pd.concat([_df.sum().astype(int), 
               _df.mean().apply("{:.2%}".format), ], 
              keys=['Count','Percentage'], axis=1)
      .loc[lambda x: x['Count']>0] #keep only columns with at least one negative value
)
   Count Percentage
a     37     37.00%
c     56     56.00%
```

Comment: what does the mean and astype(int) do  ? how can I keep only the rows with anything over 0 for the sum

Comment: @RogerSteinberg the mean basically does the sum over the len, so what in your code was `negatives/len(df)`, the astype(int) is to ensure the result is presented as integer and you don't have float representation and see the edit forselecting only columns with at least one negative value